# How to create 3D Graphic(Plotly) using javascript codes in JSP page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, 3d

In my program:

- points is a 3 dimensional list (X,Y,Z) in servlet...
- X=xi     Y=yi    Z=zi
- x1,x2,x3 variables is assigned with get() methods.

The problem: 3D graphic are not being created! I don't know how to assign "points" list elements to javascript variables... i firmly believe that the graphic could  created if the variables are  assigned...

JavaScript code:

> ```
>      <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
                <c:forEach var="Points1" items="${points}" varStatus="status">
                var x1=[ 
                    ${Points1.getX()}
                    ];

             var x2=[ 
                    ${Points1.getY()}

            ];
              var x3=[ 
                    ${Points1.getZ()}

                ];
            var data = [{
            x: x1,
            y: x2,
            z: x3,
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter3d',
            marker: {
              color: 'rgb(23, 190, 207)',
              size: 2
            }
        },{
            alphahull: 7,
            opacity: 0.1,
            type: 'mesh3d',
            x: x1,
            y: x2,
            z: x3
        }];
     </c:forEach>

        var layout = {
            autosize: true,
            height: 480,
            scene: {
                aspectratio: {
                    x: 1,
                    y: 1,
                    z: 1
                },
                camera: {
                    center: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        z: 0
                    },
                    eye: {
                        x: 1.25,
                        y: 1.25,
                        z: 1.25
                    },
                    up: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        z: 1
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    zeroline: false
                },
                yaxis: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    zeroline: false
                },
                zaxis: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    zeroline: false
                }
            },
            title: '3d point clustering',
            width: 477
        };
        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```